# youtube full screen video not calling viewWillAppear or viewWillRotate

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uiviewcontroller

So I have a UIWebView in which sometimes it has a youtube embedded player in it. When I play it and go to full screen and rotate and then dismiss the video, it doesn't call the viewWillAppear or the willRotateTo.... why is this?? I need to make some view adjustments when the device is rotated, however when the player is presented, for some reason none of these methods are being called. And yes I have shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation set correctly. Any idea?

Comment: have you tried willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation method?

Comment: that's also not getting called

Comment: have you set shouldAutoRotateToInterfaceOrientation to always YES in your App?

Comment: yes! read the question carefully in the end

Answer (score 1):

You can use following for your UIwebView problem, viewWillAppear or willRotateTo.. never calls on UIWebView. You can detect the end of full screen mode by observing the @"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification" mode:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
        selector:@selector(moviePlayerDidExitFullscreen:)
        name:@"UIMoviePlayerControllerDidExitFullscreenNotification"
        object:nil];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
}

- (void)moviePlayerDidExitFullScreen:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    // This is where you do whatever you want.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your controller must be a `UIViewController` or the `viewWillAppear` delegate won't be called.

Comment: Post more code because if it is in fact a UIViewController, then those delegates should be called.